# R: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Tags: r

I would like to make a function returning a particular column of a dataframe since I have several dataframes whose names vary of just one digit. For example, I have:

```
mtcars1 <- data.frame(name1 = mtcars[5, 1], name2 = c(1, 8, 2, 9, 9))
mtcars2 <- data.frame(name1 = mtcars[5, 1], name2 = c(1, 8, 3, 9, 9))

foo <- function(i){
  x <- paste0("mtcars", i)$name2
  return(x)
}
```

`foo(1)` is supposed to return `1 8 2 9 9` and `foo2` is supposed to return `1 8 3 9 9`

The problem is that I have the error:

> Error in paste0("mtcars", i)$name2 : 
>     $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

This is surely a straightforward question but how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `paste0("mtcars", i)$name2` returns a character vector, which can't be subset by `$`.

You can use `get` to do what you want:

```r
> mtcars1 <- data.frame(name1 = mtcars[5, 1], name2 = c(1, 8, 2, 9, 9))
> mtcars2 <- data.frame(name1 = mtcars[5, 1], name2 = c(1, 8, 3, 9, 9))
> 
> foo <- function(i){
+   x <- get(paste0("mtcars", i))$name2
+   return(x)
+ }
> foo(1)
[1] 1 8 2 9 9
> foo(2)
[1] 1 8 3 9 9
```

Comment: I was sure the solution would be quite simple, thank you :) (I have to wait a few minutes before validating)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `eval()`:

```
mtcars1 <- data.frame(name1 = mtcars[5, 1], name2 = c(1, 8, 2, 9, 9))
mtcars2 <- data.frame(name1 = mtcars[5, 1], name2 = c(1, 8, 3, 9, 9))

foo <- function(i){
      x <- eval(expr = parse(text=paste0("mtcars", i,"$name2")))
      return(x)
}

#>foo(1)
#[1] 1 8 2 9 9
#>foo(2)
#[1] 1 8 3 9 9
```

Comment: thanks, I prefer the answer of Colin FAY but this is useful too